# Check if a file exists in artifactory before downloading it shell using curl/wget from jenkins

Tags: unix, curl, artifactory

This is a common question, somehow I am not able to get it working for me. I have an artifactory folder where in I store json files.

On jenkins I am supposed to download one of the jsons e.g. Myfile.json. But this has to be done only if the file exists.

Tried  using below approaches:
Approach: 1)

```
url="https://abc/folder/Myfile.json"
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail -r 0-0 "$url"; then
echo "URL exists: $url"
else
echo "URL does not exist: $url"
fi
```

**Problem: It keeps on entering the else condition even for valid URLS.**

I'm executing the same using in bash shell. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the error code of curl request, ie

curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/

```
#!/bin/bash

url=$1

check_url=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" ${url})

#echo $check_url

case $check_url in
[200]*)
  echo "URL exists: $url" 
  ;;
[404]*)
  echo "URL does not exist: $url" 
  ;;
*)
  echo "URL error - HTTP error code $check_url: $url"
  exit 1 
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the revert....it still goes into 404 despite of a valid url. Have had the same issues with other requests as well.

Comment: really? whats the output of `curl -I http://www.example.org/` a 404 with artifactory will give you some json output, maybe you do have anonymous download enabled? whats the json it gives you?

Comment: curl -I says "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established"....the json file is one of mine which i had uploaded onto artifactory and wanted to check if it existed before downloading.

Comment: Also an interesting fact is, when i give a file what doesnt exist...the curl still creates the file in the jenkins workspace and writes below in it.                          "{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "File not found."
  } ]
}"

Comment: How to check a file exists on Artifactory ? I tried `curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/libs-test-local/123/xxx/test.zip` always return 200, but this file doesn't exist actually.

Comment: `/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/` is for the UI.

Go to a file that does exist and download that. You'll notice that rhe URL will not have  `/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/` in it. Thats he directory listing.

So try `http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/libs-test-local/` in your browser first.